# Sending the written text to screen in android

Tags: java, android

I am just a beginner in android and i created a textbox, user enters some text and presses send button, and i want this text to be sent to screen, like texting message or like whatsapp. 
I created a textbox and a button, then i added onClick method named sendAnswer to button and it is like the following:

```
    public void sendAnswer()
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        String editTextStr = editText.getText().toString();

        Log.d(editTextStr, editTextStr);
     }
```

where "answer" is the id of editText box. But this does not work. How can i do that?

Also, i will try to do the following in the next step: When user enters a text and sends it, an automatic message will be output to screen by the phone, it will be like chatting with the phone. Whatever user sends will be seen at the right hand side of the screen and whatever phone says will be seen at the left hand side of the screen. Can you give me some idea how to do these? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed android samples.
please look at how to use `ListView` and how to dynamically add items to it.

you will need a `ListView` for what you want to do.

have a look at

```
android-sdks/samples/android-8/BluetoothChat
```

it may help you.

check this example
[Manage Items dynamically](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listviewarrayadapter-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is like one way traffic. You are only getting the text from EditText to display the text on Screen you need to have two things:-

1. Have a View i.e. TextView, EditText or anything in screen to show the Text other than EditText (answer)
2. Set `editTextStr` to that using setText() to that View.

So you function should like this,

```
 public void sendAnswer()
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        String editTextStr = null;

        if(editText!=null){  //Its good to check the return value of findViewById
           editTextStr = editText.getText().toString();
        }else{
             editTextStr = "Answer EditText doesnot exists";
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output); //replace output with the ID of your new output view

        if(textView!=null){
         textView.setText(editTextStr);
        }
        Log.d(editTextStr, editTextStr);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String editTextStr;

public void sendAnswer()
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        editTextStr = editText.getText().toString();

        Log.d(editTextStr, editTextStr);
calltextview();
     }

public void calltextview()
{

  TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.chat);
  textView.setText(editTextStr);
}
```

make change in the layout like your desired design.try it.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to send the string to the next screen , use Intents

And to my Understanding point of view on your question.

You can use PutExtra(...)

Also You must Check this,

[Click here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

In the next step , You can Change the position of string in the second  activity to match your requirement.

This will surely help you...